# How to open text file in Matlab and overwrite part of it (without storing data but using fgetl to skip lines)

Tags: matlab, text

I would like to open a text file in Matlab and overwrite part of it. I dont want to store the data since its a huge file, but I want to skip the first n=213021 lines by using fgetl (or similar command), and then delete the rest and overwrite it with my data. I am trying with the code below but for some strange reason the command fprintf does not write anything. I am printing on screen the lines skipped with getl and it seems like I am in the right location. However, nothing is written with fprintf. Here a minimal example:

```
data =50:10:100;
n=4; 
fid = fopen('example.txt','r+')
for i=1:n
     fgetl(fid); %skips first n lines
end
fprintf(fid,'%i \r\n',data);
fclose(fid)
```

The example file initially reads:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And after the above code is run it should read:

```
1
2
3
4
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

but the text file is actually unchanged. Any clue?

Comment: what does variable 'data' represents inside fprintf?

Comment: Ok sorry my bad I thought it was clear it was just an example with "data" being any vector. I rewrote it by using a minimal example that can be tested and that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html#zmw57dd0e7021), you have to call `fseek` between read and write operations.

```
data =50:10:100;
n=4; 
fid = fopen('example.txt','r+')
for i=1:n
     fgetl(fid); %skips first n lines
end

fseek(fid,0,'cof');

fprintf(fid,'%i \r\n',data);
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: wow that was tricky and hard to find. At least for me.Thanks.